Series with a portal to another world with alien beings grown over with barnacle type things
In this film I remember that there was this giant portal slowly consuming a city or possibly the whole world. People could go through it and I think it led to another world.
When the people from this other world were getting sick, their skin was growing over with what looked like barnacles or something similar - until eventually they were frozen where they were and totally stuck.
I think alien (almost human looking) came through and needed help because their people were getting sick and dying from this sickness that caused them to freeze solid.
Eventually the portal closed, but everything behind it was gone, leaving a giant cliff at the end.

Welcome! Please be sure to read the tag notes before using the tags. The two tags you used for "alien/aliens" are for questions about those films, not a generic genre tag. Also, please check out our guidance for how to write a good ID question here.

Feasibility Study  from both the original and new Outer Limits TV show has aliens stealing a town, energy barriers and barnacle encrusted, frozen in place aliens.  The aliens want to enslave the humans.  The ending of the episode is fairly bleak. 
